# Among 250 consecutive answers, how many are problematic?

Tags: discussion, chatgpt

I'm curious as to the extent of the problem of AI generated answers at Stack Overflow.  So I extracted the links to 250 consecutive answers via [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search) (`is:answer`; `tab=newest`, `pagesize=50` [5 pages total]), which I've listed below, and manually inspected all of them [x2].

These answers span a bit over 4 hours.  Importantly, they do not include deleted answers (which I don't have the rep to see), so there may be AI-generated content that was deleted before I looked at it.

So how many problematic answers were there (we would expect the number to be particularly high, since this sample was taken during a moderator strike):

- 3 x suspected AI

  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76593142
  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76593006
  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76593366
  - (plus the ones in [ggorlen--on LLM strike's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/425409) which I can't see)
- 5 x not an answer (see below)
- 3 x deleted before I could read it (see below)
- 2 x spam  (see below)  (Is https://stackoverflow.com/a/76593034 spam?)
- [unknown] x deleted answers during this timeframe whose links I didn't retrieve

There was also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49031082/c-sharp-system-data-sqlclient-sqlexception-failed-to-generate-sspi-context/76593151#76593151) which looks a bit weird.

I just thought I'd share this with the community; I believe it's helpful to get more objective data, especially concerning the extent of the problem.  I encourage someone who can see all the deleted answers (maybe this has to be Stack Exchange staff) to repeat this experiment.  Yes, it takes time, but it's concrete evidence, and it's actually an interesting exercise to figure out what's different between human and AI answers.

---

1. [Show UIMenu when single-tapping UIBarButtonItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63299837/show-uimenu-when-single-tapping-uibarbuttonitem/76593376?r=SearchResults#76593376)
2. [Cannot open OpenCL Settings in Cytoscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71707271/cannot-open-opencl-settings-in-cytoscape/76593374?r=SearchResults#76593374) (not an answer)
3. [i have error to recognize folder in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592760/i-have-error-to-recognize-folder-in-node-js/76593370?r=SearchResults#76593370)
4. [Forcing CPU/ABI to armeabi-v7a on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37246792/forcing-cpu-abi-to-armeabi-v7a-on-android/76593367?r=SearchResults#76593367)
5. [Jpa @Query Annotation problem with using IN clause with java ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76593358/jpa-query-annotation-problem-to-use-in-clause-with-java-arraylist/76593366?r=SearchResults#76593366) (suspected AI-generated)
6. [Flutter webview throws PlatformException(NSInternalInconsistencyException,InstanceManager does not contain an NSURL with identifier:65540, null, null)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76499166/flutter-webview-throws-platformexceptionnsinternalinconsistencyexception-instan/76593365?r=SearchResults#76593365)
7. [Can you declare multiple variable types for function arguments if you have multiple types to declare? (Golang)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76593212/can-you-declare-multiple-variable-types-for-function-arguments-if-you-have-multi/76593363?r=SearchResults#76593363)
8. [Azure function app billing per app when using a shared plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76590891/azure-function-app-billing-per-app-when-using-a-shared-plan/76593361?r=SearchResults#76593361)
9. [How to combine a RepeatListener in Android with a smooth image rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76431011/how-to-combine-a-repeatlistener-in-android-with-a-smooth-image-rotation/76593359?r=SearchResults#76593359)
10. [How does typescript narrow generics？](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76561737/how-does-typescript-narrow-generics/76593350?r=SearchResults#76593350)
11. [How to create datagrid combobox in WinUI 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592229/how-to-create-datagrid-combobox-in-winui-3/76593348?r=SearchResults#76593348)
12. [Trying to compress pdf file stored in AWS S3 bucket using AWS Lambda with python but it showing Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76593312/trying-to-compress-pdf-file-stored-in-aws-s3-bucket-using-aws-lambda-with-python/76593347?r=SearchResults#76593347)
13. [Process file uploaded with a fetch post request with request.on in node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76535567/process-file-uploaded-with-a-fetch-post-request-with-request-on-in-node-js/76593345?r=SearchResults#76593345)
14. [Formatting an input by counting characters until a symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76593159/formatting-an-input-by-counting-characters-until-a-symbol/76593344?r=SearchResults#76593344)
15. [Error pinging docker server on "terraform apply"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67989620/error-pinging-docker-server-on-terraform-apply/76593343?r=SearchResults#76593343)
16. [Splitting Columns in Pandas DataFrame by a Specific String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76593310/splitting-columns-in-pandas-dataframe-by-a-specific-string/76593341?r=SearchResults#76593341)
17. [Cloud Firestore - this document has no data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76591848/cloud-firestore-this-document-has-no-data/76593340?r=SearchResults#76593340)
18. [Splitting Columns in Pandas DataFrame by a Specific String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76593310/splitting-columns-in-pandas-dataframe-by-a-specific-string/76593339?r=SearchResults#76593339)
19. [How to pass template parameter of a function to a lambda in the function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76593156/how-to-pass-template-parameter-of-a-function-to-a-lambda-in-the-function/76593336?r=SearchResults#76593336)
20. [Testing MS Team's Tab with different Organization:MS GraphAPI AADSTS65001: user or administrator has not consented to use the application with<app-id>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76437392/testing-ms-teams-tab-with-different-organizationms-graphapi-aadsts65001-user/76593331?r=SearchResults#76593331)
21. [How to treat ALL C# 8 nullable reference warnings as errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58194983/how-to-treat-all-c-sharp-8-nullable-reference-warnings-as-errors/76593327?r=SearchResults#76593327)
22. [How to have field validation call when submitting a field value (not the whole form) - Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592781/how-to-have-field-validation-call-when-submitting-a-field-value-not-the-whole-f/76593326?r=SearchResults#76593326)
23. [Terraform creating S3 Bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592258/terraform-creating-s3-bucket/76593323?r=SearchResults#76593323)
24. [The Package Conflicts With An Existing Package By The Same Name Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76528736/the-package-conflicts-with-an-existing-package-by-the-same-name-error/76593322?r=SearchResults#76593322)
25. [Post Function is not giving output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76593164/post-function-is-not-giving-output/76593321?r=SearchResults#76593321)
26. [how to use npm package with hugo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70157040/how-to-use-npm-package-with-hugo/76593320?r=SearchResults#76593320)
27. [Airflow Standalone Cannot use relative path:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72194598/airflow-standalone-cannot-use-relative-path/76593319?r=SearchResults#76593319)
28. [How to detect changes on an Angular @Input array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592660/how-to-detect-changes-on-an-angular-input-array/76593318?r=SearchResults#76593318)
29. [apend method is not working in python code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76593300/apend-method-is-not-working-in-python-code/76593315?r=SearchResults#76593315)
30. [Endpoint for Azure model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76589496/endpoint-for-azure-model/76593314?r=SearchResults#76593314)
31. [Cannot import name 'available_if' from 'sklearn.utils.metaestimators'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69602057/cannot-import-name-available-if-from-sklearn-utils-metaestimators/76593313?r=SearchResults#76593313)
32. [How can I incorporate cluster-robust standard errors into a randomization test using the 'ritest' function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76593038/how-can-i-incorporate-cluster-robust-standard-errors-into-a-randomization-test-u/76593307?r=SearchResults#76593307)
33. [Script to remove Python comments/docstrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769332/script-to-remove-python-comments-docstrings/76593305?r=SearchResults#76593305)
34. [i am using multiple nestjs servers and i am using nginx as a api-gateway from the front to the the specific backend server but its not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76593011/i-am-using-multiple-nestjs-servers-and-i-am-using-nginx-as-a-api-gateway-from-th/76593303?r=SearchResults#76593303)
35. [Error: Failed to create keystore in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75725688/error-failed-to-create-keystore-in-android-studio/76593302?r=SearchResults#76593302)
36. [How to inherit from std::ostream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772355/how-to-inherit-from-stdostream/76593298?r=SearchResults#76593298)
37. [Add-Migration fails on WinUI 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592387/add-migration-fails-on-winui-3/76593297?r=SearchResults#76593297)
38. [Spring boot deployed in Lambda throws "statusCode": 502 Gateway timeout"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76577207/spring-boot-deployed-in-lambda-throws-statuscode-502-gateway-timeout/76593294?r=SearchResults#76593294)
39. [Post Function is not giving output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76593164/post-function-is-not-giving-output/76593293?r=SearchResults#76593293)
40. [Obtain max-width using JS in px when it is defined in other units in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592721/obtain-max-width-using-js-in-px-when-it-is-defined-in-other-units-in-css/76593292?r=SearchResults#76593292)
41. [Qt configure warning No backend for low level audio found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76191389/qt-configure-warning-no-backend-for-low-level-audio-found/76593291?r=SearchResults#76593291)
42. [Recovering one specific future in a future composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76587480/recovering-one-specific-future-in-a-future-composition/76593285?r=SearchResults#76593285)
43. [Problem for check if sql request return a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76593181/problem-for-check-if-sql-request-return-a-value/76593283?r=SearchResults#76593283)
44. [How do I assign another owner for my Azure Tenant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76590015/how-do-i-assign-another-owner-for-my-azure-tenant/76593282?r=SearchResults#76593282)
45. [QML module not found (QtLocation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76589514/qml-module-not-found-qtlocation/76593281?r=SearchResults#76593281)
46. [Previous firebase query code no longer works, after npm audit fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76593190/previous-firebase-query-code-no-longer-works-after-npm-audit-fix/76593280?r=SearchResults#76593280)
47. [How to change the order in which parameters are arranged in the body of post to a soap api from an azure portal custom connector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76590093/how-to-change-the-order-in-which-parameters-are-arranged-in-the-body-of-post-to/76593279?r=SearchResults#76593279) (deleted before I could read it)
48. [Adding external CSS in an HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947878/adding-external-css-in-an-html-file/76593277?r=SearchResults#76593277)
49. [How to change the order in which parameters are arranged in the body of post to a soap api from an azure portal custom connector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76590093/how-to-change-the-order-in-which-parameters-are-arranged-in-the-body-of-post-to/76593276?r=SearchResults#76593276)
50. [Fails to read GMAIL inbox with "Invalid credentials (Failure)" when setting up ImapFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75344054/fails-to-read-gmail-inbox-with-invalid-credentials-failure-when-setting-up-i/76593275?r=SearchResults#76593275)
51. [How to export a declared external value as a named export?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68133038/how-to-export-a-declared-external-value-as-a-named-export/76593274?r=SearchResults#76593274)
52. [CSS: How to constantly display the bottom of the screen in a overflow window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76593069/css-how-to-constantly-display-the-bottom-of-the-screen-in-a-overflow-window/76593273?r=SearchResults#76593273)
53. ["GraphQLError: field not found in type: 'query_root'" after merge schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56702835/graphqlerror-field-not-found-in-type-query-root-after-merge-schema/76593272?r=SearchResults#76593272)
54. [Mongodb + Atlas: 'bad auth Authentication failed.', code: 8000,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60020381/mongodb-atlas-bad-auth-authentication-failed-code-8000/76593271?r=SearchResults#76593271)
55. [Expanding a symbolic multivariate polynomial with R for usage in POV-Ray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76593269/expanding-a-symbolic-multivariate-polynomial-with-r-for-usage-in-pov-ray/76593270?r=SearchResults#76593270)
56. [How to completely uninstall django-taggit from my project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55030294/how-to-completely-uninstall-django-taggit-from-my-project/76593267?r=SearchResults#76593267)
57. [Navbar hides when page hits top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68880080/navbar-hides-when-page-hits-top/76593265?r=SearchResults#76593265)
58. [Angular material form field is not updating when changing values in the component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592957/angular-material-form-field-is-not-updating-when-changing-values-in-the-componen/76593264?r=SearchResults#76593264)
59. [The relationship between interrupts and process scheduling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76573744/the-relationship-between-interrupts-and-process-scheduling/76593263?r=SearchResults#76593263)
60. [error express-handlebars@7.0.1 when deploying nodejs app to render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75675279/error-express-handlebars7-0-1-when-deploying-nodejs-app-to-render/76593262?r=SearchResults#76593262)
61. [Why is there nothing like PgBouncer for Mongo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70109445/why-is-there-nothing-like-pgbouncer-for-mongo/76593261?r=SearchResults#76593261)
62. [How do you import an enum into a different namespace in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293279/how-do-you-import-an-enum-into-a-different-namespace-in-c/76593260?r=SearchResults#76593260)
63. [How to universally enable scrolling on website that disabled scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39360138/how-to-universally-enable-scrolling-on-website-that-disabled-scrolling/76593259?r=SearchResults#76593259)
64. [Optimizing Matrix Multiplication in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76593250/optimizing-matrix-multiplication-in-python/76593258?r=SearchResults#76593258)
65. [How to have more than one case statement for a column in adf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76589672/how-to-have-more-than-one-case-statement-for-a-column-in-adf/76593257?r=SearchResults#76593257)
66. [ImportError: cannot import name 'Annotated' from 'pydantic.typing' when using inflect library in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76593169/importerror-cannot-import-name-annotated-from-pydantic-typing-when-using-in/76593254?r=SearchResults#76593254)
67. [Cannot exclude DataSourceAutoConfiguration for it is not auto-configuation class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592864/cannot-exclude-datasourceautoconfiguration-for-it-is-not-auto-configuation-class/76593253?r=SearchResults#76593253)
68. [Spring possibility to @Value on a Pojo / object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65365181/spring-possibility-to-value-on-a-pojo-object/76593252?r=SearchResults#76593252)
69. [ASP .NET application is trying to use local paths to open a file when I have changed the code to use HTTP paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76591942/asp-net-application-is-trying-to-use-local-paths-to-open-a-file-when-i-have-cha/76593249?r=SearchResults#76593249)
70. [Non-greedy regex extraction from JSON with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76593228/non-greedy-regex-extraction-from-json-with-sed/76593246?r=SearchResults#76593246)
71. [Python psycopg2 not able to connect to postgres server "psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host, no encryption"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76583406/python-psycopg2-not-able-to-connect-to-postgres-server-psycopg2-operationalerro/76593241?r=SearchResults#76593241)
72. [Passing multiple cookies to puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50584770/passing-multiple-cookies-to-puppeteer/76593240?r=SearchResults#76593240)
73. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76593157/hi-guys-im-making-a-website-and-i-wanted-it-not-to-look-like-this-when-adapted/76593238?r=SearchResults#76593238
74. [How to override User Defined Variable from JSR223 PreProcessor in Jmetr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76591402/how-to-override-user-defined-variable-from-jsr223-preprocessor-in-jmetr/76593237?r=SearchResults#76593237)
75. [How to copy and paste the last row until a certain date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76583920/how-to-copy-and-paste-the-last-row-until-a-certain-date/76593235?r=SearchResults#76593235)
76. [Filter JSON Data upto 2nd or 3rd Level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76588758/filter-json-data-upto-2nd-or-3rd-level/76593232?r=SearchResults#76593232)
77. ["Begin size 0 is not equal to fixed size 5" Error in JMeter while generating HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69097274/begin-size-0-is-not-equal-to-fixed-size-5-error-in-jmeter-while-generating-htm/76593231?r=SearchResults#76593231)
78. [How to get desktop heap free size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422217/how-to-get-desktop-heap-free-size/76593230?r=SearchResults#76593230)
79. [How to list prometheus alerts in a dashboard in grafana?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76590925/how-to-list-prometheus-alerts-in-a-dashboard-in-grafana/76593225?r=SearchResults#76593225)
80. [Could async methods that change the same value be a concurrency problem in Flutter Web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76593119/could-async-methods-that-change-the-same-value-be-a-concurrency-problem-in-flutt/76593224?r=SearchResults#76593224)
81. [How to active a user after creating one with LDAP.JS/LDAP.TS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76591892/how-to-active-a-user-after-creating-one-with-ldap-js-ldap-ts/76593223?r=SearchResults#76593223)
82. [How to resolve error in 'flutter.gradle' line 1201 that prevents app execution on devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76378638/how-to-resolve-error-in-flutter-gradle-line-1201-that-prevents-app-execution-o/76593222?r=SearchResults#76593222)
83. [State communication between child and parent in React.js not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76593143/state-communication-between-child-and-parent-in-react-js-not-working/76593216?r=SearchResults#76593216)
84. [Is there an activity monitor for VS Code extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592863/is-there-an-activity-monitor-for-vs-code-extensions/76593213?r=SearchResults#76593213)
85. [Fastify Response Validation not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76123308/fastify-response-validation-not-working-as-expected/76593211?r=SearchResults#76593211)
86. [Playing sound using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74083314/playing-sound-using-python/76593209?r=SearchResults#76593209)
87. [Selenium: How to keep scrolling the page and stop scrolling when the target url is met?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76589819/selenium-how-to-keep-scrolling-the-page-and-stop-scrolling-when-the-target-url/76593207?r=SearchResults#76593207)
88. [javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76587843/javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-in-android-studio/76593206?r=SearchResults#76593206)
89. [How to pass an argument to dc_shell in tcl mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65246773/how-to-pass-an-argument-to-dc-shell-in-tcl-mode/76593205?r=SearchResults#76593205)
90. [Why is my PyTorch code 10x slower than the TensorFlow version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76591762/why-is-my-pytorch-code-10x-slower-than-the-tensorflow-version/76593200?r=SearchResults#76593200)
91. [Send call back to previous fragment with data using navigation graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76524097/send-call-back-to-previous-fragment-with-data-using-navigation-graph/76593199?r=SearchResults#76593199)
92. [Terraform creating S3 Bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592258/terraform-creating-s3-bucket/76593196?r=SearchResults#76593196)
93. [How to reset a postgresql cursor with psycopg2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76590440/how-to-reset-a-postgresql-cursor-with-psycopg2/76593195?r=SearchResults#76593195)
94. [How can I pass multiple implementations of a generic (which must also conform to a protocol) into my Model struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592601/how-can-i-pass-multiple-implementations-of-a-generic-which-must-also-conform-to/76593194?r=SearchResults#76593194)
95. [Is there a way to get lifted tabs in daisyUI to use the full width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76161321/is-there-a-way-to-get-lifted-tabs-in-daisyui-to-use-the-full-width/76593193?r=SearchResults#76593193)
96. [How to detect the movement of the sash of a ttk.Panedwindow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592290/how-to-detect-the-movement-of-the-sash-of-a-ttk-panedwindow/76593192?r=SearchResults#76593192)
97. [Why does it say module has no attribute text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76593096/why-does-it-say-module-has-no-attribute-text/76593189?r=SearchResults#76593189)
98. [WPF TwoWay Binding Not Working on TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76593129/wpf-twoway-binding-not-working-on-textbox/76593188?r=SearchResults#76593188)
99. [Terraform filebase64 on pfx certificate difference vs azurerm_key_vault_certificate.kvtcert.certificate_data_base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76583752/terraform-filebase64-on-pfx-certificate-difference-vs-azurerm-key-vault-certific/76593183?r=SearchResults#76593183)
100. [Why is a FetchContent using a different TAG than the one I specified? How can I resolve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76593109/force-a-tag-with-fetchcontent-getting-an-older-version/76593182?r=SearchResults#76593182)
101. [Can I restrict users who're authenticated anonymously in firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76593131/can-i-restrict-users-whore-authenticated-anonymously-in-firebase/76593179?r=SearchResults#76593179)
102. [Why do I get overload error while using std::enable_if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76593060/why-do-i-get-overload-error-while-using-stdenable-if/76593178?r=SearchResults#76593178)
103. [Set Django send_mail backend host with Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72794731/set-django-send-mail-backend-host-with-gmail/76593173?r=SearchResults#76593173)
104. [How to access Service in MAUI Lifecycle Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76588232/how-to-access-service-in-maui-lifecycle-event/76593170?r=SearchResults#76593170)
105. [useReducer stockpiles component renders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76584614/usereducer-stockpiles-component-renders/76593168?r=SearchResults#76593168)
106. [Can I change the default Markdown font color in VS Code Jupyter Notebooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74649843/can-i-change-the-default-markdown-font-color-in-vs-code-jupyter-notebooks/76593166?r=SearchResults#76593166)
107. [Accessing sharepoint list with token unclear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66329759/accessing-sharepoint-list-with-token-unclear/76593163?r=SearchResults#76593163)
108. [Send header in HTTP post request in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73984252/send-header-in-http-post-request-in-flutter/76593154?r=SearchResults#76593154)
109. [NextAuth.js - Credentials signIn always returns ok=true when redirect=false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76350945/nextauth-js-credentials-signin-always-returns-ok-true-when-redirect-false/76593153?r=SearchResults#76593153)
110. [C# - System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Failed to generate SSPI context.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49031082/c-sharp-system-data-sqlclient-sqlexception-failed-to-generate-sspi-context/76593151?r=SearchResults#76593151) (kind of weirdly written; maybe copy/pasted from somewhere, but not AI)
111. [Scraping saved comments and posts from Reddit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76590877/scraping-saved-comments-and-posts-from-reddit/76593149?r=SearchResults#76593149)
112. [Android BottomSheet bounce animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71615874/android-bottomsheet-bounce-animation/76593146?r=SearchResults#76593146)
113. [Image is not being upload Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592653/image-is-not-being-upload-django/76593145?r=SearchResults#76593145)
114. [Android biometric - How to detect biometric is lockout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76593125/android-biometric-how-to-detect-biometric-is-lockout/76593142?r=SearchResults#76593142) (suspected AI-generated [user has a pattern])
115. [DIscord bot not detecting any messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76590774/discord-bot-not-detecting-any-messages/76593140?r=SearchResults#76593140)
116. [Define functions expression - Clarity Smart contract Stacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75855386/define-functions-expression-clarity-smart-contract-stacks/76593137?r=SearchResults#76593137)
117. [Nothing appears when opening an HTML file with Folium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592979/i-dont-see-anything-when-opening-the-html-file/76593136?r=SearchResults#76593136)
118. [Google Sign-In Not Working in Next.js with Firebase due to Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76555769/google-sign-in-not-working-in-next-js-with-firebase-due-to-cross-origin-opener-p/76593135?r=SearchResults#76593135)
119. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76593107/langchain-how-to-get-the-pdf-page-number-when-showing-a-result/76593134?r=SearchResults#76593134 (deleted before I could read it)
120. [React vitejs Unexpected string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76527409/react-vitejs-unexpected-string/76593130?r=SearchResults#76593130)
121. [--recurse ERROR: Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54656014/recurse-error-insufficient-permission-request-had-insufficient-authenticatio/76593128?r=SearchResults#76593128)
122. [Encrypting a stream with ChaCha20Poly1305](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76588700/encrypting-a-stream-with-chacha20poly1305/76593127?r=SearchResults#76593127)
123. [Why do I get overload error while using std::enable_if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76593060/why-do-i-get-overload-error-while-using-stdenable-if/76593124?r=SearchResults#76593124)
124. [How to access query parameters in Next.js 13.4 with the new app router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592804/how-to-access-query-parameters-in-next-js-13-4-with-the-new-app-router/76593123?r=SearchResults#76593123)
125. [Directional network graph in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592790/directional-network-graph-in-javascript/76593122?r=SearchResults#76593122)
126. [Cannot set property closed of #<Readable> which has only a getter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74240482/cannot-set-property-closed-of-readable-which-has-only-a-getter/76593121?r=SearchResults#76593121)
127. [How do I write a SQL query to display course_id, course_name and fee collected from each course?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44973957/how-do-i-write-a-sql-query-to-display-course-id-course-name-and-fee-collected-f/76593115?r=SearchResults#76593115)
128. [trouble installing apache.logging.log4j and slf4j on the build.sbt of my Scala Spark project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76566913/trouble-installing-apache-logging-log4j-and-slf4j-on-the-build-sbt-of-my-scala-s/76593110?r=SearchResults#76593110)
129. [Is there a way to use the sep="" function with an inputed string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76593091/is-there-a-way-to-use-the-sep-function-with-an-inputed-string/76593108?r=SearchResults#76593108)
130. [‘Invalid color name error’ when using multiple color palette as a nested list in shiny selectInput for sf plot function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76593083/invalid-color-name-error-when-using-multiple-color-palette-as-a-nested-list-in/76593105?r=SearchResults#76593105)
131. [Get all baklink domains of any particular domain using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15661142/get-all-baklink-domains-of-any-particular-domain-using-php/76593101?r=SearchResults#76593101) (spam)
132. [App Tracking Transparency on Flutter was rejected by Apple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70699164/app-tracking-transparency-on-flutter-was-rejected-by-apple/76593099?r=SearchResults#76593099)
133. [How to fetch elements w/ listitem role using Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76591722/how-to-fetch-elements-w-listitem-role-using-selenium/76593094?r=SearchResults#76593094)
134. [javascript: detect scroll end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962558/javascript-detect-scroll-end/76593087?r=SearchResults#76593087)
135. [Is it possible to accept credit card payments on a static site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76591360/is-it-possible-to-accept-credit-card-payments-on-a-static-site/76593084?r=SearchResults#76593084)
136. [C# How to use ISupportExternalScope with customer ILogger/ILoggerProvider and middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592214/c-sharp-how-to-use-isupportexternalscope-with-customer-ilogger-iloggerprovider-a/76593082?r=SearchResults#76593082)
137. [Slack bot post mesage to usergroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76583808/slack-bot-post-mesage-to-usergroup/76593079?r=SearchResults#76593079)
138. [Always Unauthorized POST request with JWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76397150/always-unauthorized-post-request-with-jwt/76593072?r=SearchResults#76593072)
139. [How to get a Python Style Traceback in Ironpython3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76586161/how-to-get-a-python-style-traceback-in-ironpython3/76593065?r=SearchResults#76593065)
140. [Passing CSV columns to a command in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592562/passing-csv-columns-to-a-command-in-bash/76593063?r=SearchResults#76593063)
141. [Define Non Fungible Token - Stacks Clarity Smart Contract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75857040/define-non-fungible-token-stacks-clarity-smart-contract/76593062?r=SearchResults#76593062)
142. [How does extern "C" affect linking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76593037/how-does-extern-c-affect-linking/76593061?r=SearchResults#76593061)
143. [Python in VS Code Not Allowing Implicit Line Continuation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592606/python-in-vs-code-not-allowing-implicit-line-continuation/76593050?r=SearchResults#76593050)
144. [Vuetify v-select prop type check failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76590545/vuetify-v-select-prop-type-check-failure/76593049?r=SearchResults#76593049)
145. [JSONObject(doc.text()) not working in a particular case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76588875/jsonobjectdoc-text-not-working-in-a-particular-case/76593046?r=SearchResults#76593046) (spam)
146. [Dealing with an API with a lot of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592708/dealing-with-an-api-with-a-lot-of-data/76593044?r=SearchResults#76593044)
147. [I am getting this Error: Field '_controller' should be initialized because its type 'AnimationController' doesn't allow null. How do I instantiate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592995/i-am-getting-this-error-field-controller-should-be-initialized-because-its-t/76593039?r=SearchResults#76593039)
148. [expect script failing on exec command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592908/expect-script-failing-on-exec-command/76593036?r=SearchResults#76593036)
149. [Dropdown menu in nav is overlapping behind content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592860/dropdown-menu-in-nav-is-overlapping-behind-content/76593035?r=SearchResults#76593035)
150. [Web API dynamic parameters for filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37026949/web-api-dynamic-parameters-for-filtering/76593034?r=SearchResults#76593034) (possible spam; I'm not sure)
151. [I am going through the chainlink functions tutorial and trying to deploy FunctionsConsumer contract and getting an error from undici](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76077710/i-am-going-through-the-chainlink-functions-tutorial-and-trying-to-deploy-functio/76593031?r=SearchResults#76593031)
152. [Is there a way to import IntelliJ IDEA theme in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46527500/is-there-a-way-to-import-intellij-idea-theme-in-visual-studio/76593030?r=SearchResults#76593030)
153. [Running two Streamlit functions at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592916/running-two-streamlit-functions-at-the-same-time/76593029?r=SearchResults#76593029) (deleted before I could read it)
154. [How to achieve crawling web and waiting for specific event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76587522/how-to-achieve-crawling-web-and-waiting-for-specific-event/76593028?r=SearchResults#76593028)
155. [Ant Design - Upload file into memory before posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70894188/ant-design-upload-file-into-memory-before-posting/76593027?r=SearchResults#76593027) (not an answer)
156. [reading in tab delimited text file with tidyverse readr - columns not parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592893/reading-in-tab-delimited-text-file-with-tidyverse-readr-columns-not-parsing/76593026?r=SearchResults#76593026)
157. [how i can put two action for a html-python from?(Django)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592086/how-i-can-put-two-action-for-a-html-python-fromdjango/76593025?r=SearchResults#76593025)
158. [Properly implement a full-screen background image in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76588056/properly-implement-a-full-screen-background-image-in-swiftui/76593024?r=SearchResults#76593024)
159. [Breaking c++ 20 module dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66771232/breaking-c-20-module-dependencies/76593023?r=SearchResults#76593023)
160. [Why is useEffect render-blocking(paint-blocking) in the tooltip example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76536019/why-is-useeffect-render-blockingpaint-blocking-in-the-tooltip-example/76593022?r=SearchResults#76593022)
161. [Is there an activity monitor for VS Code extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592863/is-there-an-activity-monitor-for-vs-code-extensions/76593021?r=SearchResults#76593021)
162. [Loop for writing in every sheet without erasing the previous data - EDIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76590688/loop-for-writing-in-every-sheet-without-erasing-the-previous-data/76593020?r=SearchResults#76593020)
163. [Pandas is not aggregating a simple data frame correctly. Is it a bug, or my platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592932/pandas-is-not-aggregating-correctly-a-simple-data-frame-is-it-a-bug-or-my-plat/76593012?r=SearchResults#76593012)
164. [TypeORMError: Driver not Connected - NestJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592082/typeormerror-driver-not-connected-nestjs/76593006?r=SearchResults#76593006) (suspected AI-generated)
165. [Exporting data from C# to Excel version error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73150050/exporting-data-from-c-sharp-to-excel-version-error/76593004?r=SearchResults#76593004)
166. [Converting grouped records (either DataFrame or SQL table) into a JSON array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76544243/converting-grouped-records-either-dataframe-or-sql-table-into-a-json-array-of/76593002?r=SearchResults#76593002)
167. [How can I make VS Code check for errors when referencing properties of JSON imported into JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74821817/how-can-i-make-vs-code-check-for-errors-when-referencing-properties-of-json-impo/76592998?r=SearchResults#76592998)
168. [Can we use data directly from RDS or df as a data source for training job in Sagemaker, rather than pulling it from from s3 or EFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70578172/can-we-use-data-directly-from-rds-or-df-as-a-data-source-for-training-job-in-sag/76592997?r=SearchResults#76592997)
169. [Rails Enum '0' is not a valid incomeType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49851690/rails-enum-0-is-not-a-valid-incometype/76592996?r=SearchResults#76592996)
170. [importxml formula google spreadhseets does not display required data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76590001/importxml-formula-google-spreadhseets-does-not-display-required-data/76592993?r=SearchResults#76592993)
171. [How to enforce minimum delay between events from Combine publisher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76589560/how-to-enforce-minimum-delay-between-events-from-combine-publisher/76592991?r=SearchResults#76592991)
172. [Radio button not taking the value as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592903/radio-button-not-taking-the-value-as-expected/76592989?r=SearchResults#76592989)
173. [MPAndroidChart - hide missing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592508/mpandroidchart-hide-missing-data/76592985?r=SearchResults#76592985)
174. [Express, error - connectRedis is not a function - Solved the problem by installing connect-redis version 6 instead of 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76539488/express-error-connectredis-is-not-a-function-solved-the-problem-by-installi/76592984?r=SearchResults#76592984)
175. [How to highlight text using readline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592853/how-to-highlight-text-using-readline/76592983?r=SearchResults#76592983)
176. [Insert userID and Password with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76589805/insert-userid-and-password-with-selenium/76592982?r=SearchResults#76592982)
177. [More precise sleep (usleep) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72201261/more-precise-sleep-usleep-in-python/76592978?r=SearchResults#76592978)
178. [How to get the status of a fetch correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592954/how-to-get-the-status-of-a-fetch-correctly/76592977?r=SearchResults#76592977)
179. [Spring JPA + Hibernate + Postgres - unable to perform "FOR UPDATE OF" query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76590312/spring-jpa-hibernate-postgres-unable-to-perform-for-update-of-query/76592975?r=SearchResults#76592975)
180. [Send one email with table (specific columns)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592928/send-one-email-with-table-specific-columns/76592973?r=SearchResults#76592973)
181. [XPath expression fails to return correct elements in Selenium (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71946262/xpath-expression-fails-to-return-correct-elements-in-selenium-java/76592971?r=SearchResults#76592971)
182. [Recursive function to calculate 25% of the sum of what is returned before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592925/recursive-function-to-calculate-25-of-the-sum-of-what-is-returned-before/76592970?r=SearchResults#76592970)
183. [How can I solve the AttributeError: 'Snake' object has no attribute 'distance'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76551741/how-can-i-solve-the-attributeerror-snake-object-has-no-attribute-distance/76592969?r=SearchResults#76592969)
184. [I'm getting error CS1003. How do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592950/im-getting-error-cs1003-how-do-i-fix-it/76592967?r=SearchResults#76592967)
185. [Recursive function to calculate 25% of the sum of what is returned before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592925/recursive-function-to-calculate-25-of-the-sum-of-what-is-returned-before/76592961?r=SearchResults#76592961)
186. [Clarity Smart contract validate principal calling public function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75857061/clarity-smart-contract-validate-principal-calling-public-function/76592960?r=SearchResults#76592960)
187. [Multer: "ENOENT: no such file or directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592912/multer-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory/76592959?r=SearchResults#76592959)
188. [Pandas is not aggregating a simple data frame correctly. Is it a bug, or my platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592932/pandas-is-not-aggregating-correctly-a-simple-data-frame-is-it-a-bug-or-my-plat/76592958?r=SearchResults#76592958)
189. [How to plot squares using lists in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592910/how-to-plot-squares-using-lists-in-python/76592955?r=SearchResults#76592955)
190. [what is the major difference GridView and GridView.builder in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592638/what-is-the-major-difference-gridview-and-gridview-builder-in-flutter/76592951?r=SearchResults#76592951)
191. [Return type of HashMap put() vs compute()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592756/return-type-of-hashmap-put-vs-compute/76592949?r=SearchResults#76592949)
192. [Why my SysLink control appears as plain text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592481/why-my-syslink-control-appears-as-plain-text/76592948?r=SearchResults#76592948)
193. [What is this error and how to fix it?: ValueError: Invalid value supplied 'WktVersion.WKT2_2019'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592778/what-is-this-error-and-how-to-fix-it-valueerror-invalid-value-supplied-wktve/76592946?r=SearchResults#76592946)
194. [In my Express Routes When I use '/' end point in my router, it works, however when I change the endpoint to '/login' it doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592797/in-my-express-routes-when-i-use-end-point-in-my-router-it-works-however-wh/76592945?r=SearchResults#76592945)
195. ["Empty Subscriber" in Swift Combine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76582391/empty-subscriber-in-swift-combine/76592943?r=SearchResults#76592943)
196. [Return type of HashMap put() vs compute()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592756/return-type-of-hashmap-put-vs-compute/76592942?r=SearchResults#76592942)
197. [What's the role of unification in Coq's core type system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76561105/whats-the-role-of-unification-in-coqs-core-type-system/76592940?r=SearchResults#76592940)
198. [How does memory alloc work in C? // What's wrong w my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592892/how-does-memory-alloc-work-in-c-whats-wrong-w-my-code/76592939?r=SearchResults#76592939)
199. [Report for getting followups outside of start_date parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592575/report-for-getting-followups-outside-of-start-date-parameter/76592938?r=SearchResults#76592938)
200. [How to loop this css slider animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27986016/how-to-loop-this-css-slider-animation/76592937?r=SearchResults#76592937) (not an answer)
201. [GitHub Actions - Use `on` to filter by source and target branch for PR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592824/github-actions-use-on-to-filter-by-source-and-target-branch-for-pr/76592934?r=SearchResults#76592934)
202. [Unable to upadate combo box in tkinter python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592844/unable-to-upadate-combo-box-in-tkinter-python/76592931?r=SearchResults#76592931)
203. [expect script failing on exec command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592908/expect-script-failing-on-exec-command/76592930?r=SearchResults#76592930)
204. [How can I make the suggestions widget appear "automatically" for a completion provider in a VS Code extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74837030/how-can-i-make-the-suggestions-widget-appear-automatically-for-a-completion-pr/76592929?r=SearchResults#76592929)
205. [running make is failing from boost::bind with _1 and _2 placeholders...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592898/running-make-is-failing-from-boostbind-with-1-and-2-placeholders/76592927?r=SearchResults#76592927)
206. [bridge-nf-call-iptables and bridge-nf-call-ip6tables disabled on WSL2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63226322/bridge-nf-call-iptables-and-bridge-nf-call-ip6tables-disabled-on-wsl2/76592926?r=SearchResults#76592926)
207. [Nextjs 13 Api Route remains static when calling with cache:no-store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76460240/nextjs-13-api-route-remains-static-when-calling-with-cacheno-store/76592923?r=SearchResults#76592923)
208. [Radio button not taking the value as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592903/radio-button-not-taking-the-value-as-expected/76592922?r=SearchResults#76592922)
209. [CORS: "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.", but pre-flight data shows that it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76582729/cors-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resou/76592920?r=SearchResults#76592920)
210. [How to have field validation call when submitting a field value (not the whole form) - Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592781/how-to-have-field-validation-call-when-submitting-a-field-value-not-the-whole-f/76592919?r=SearchResults#76592919)
211. [The problem of misdiagnosing the max() function in returning the largest feature value of nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592360/the-problem-of-misdiagnosing-the-max-function-in-returning-the-largest-feature/76592917?r=SearchResults#76592917)
212. [Enable findAll function to handle > 3 digit currency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76590305/enable-findall-function-to-handle-3-digit-currency/76592913?r=SearchResults#76592913)
213. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41225711/wsl-run-linux-from-windows-without-spawning-a-cmd-window/76592901?r=SearchResults#76592901
214. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68411057/how-to-run-storage-link-command-on-forge/76592899?r=SearchResults#76592899
215. [How does memory alloc work in C? // What's wrong w my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592892/how-does-memory-alloc-work-in-c-whats-wrong-w-my-code/76592897?r=SearchResults#76592897)
216. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76534289/adding-javascript-hotkeys-to-date-controls-for-increased-efficiency-entering-dat/76592896?r=SearchResults#76592896
217. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592808/how-to-give-inside-padding-to-a-text-in-swift-ui/76592895?r=SearchResults#76592895
218. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342324/how-can-i-connect-to-sap-using-sapnwrfc-library/76592894?r=SearchResults#76592894 (not an answer)
219. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592265/why-wont-my-vba-code-loop-through-subfolders-correctly/76592891?r=SearchResults#76592891
220. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592830/how-to-remove-a-limited-number-of-characters-before-a-in-a-string/76592889?r=SearchResults#76592889
221. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592858/how-to-perform-a-series-of-multiplication-with-one-of-the-multiplier-as-the-prod/76592887?r=SearchResults#76592887
222. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76582892/using-a-udf-based-on-a-group-of-keys-in-order-to-build-a-new-column-using-spark/76592886?r=SearchResults#76592886
223. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76561104/unity-error-could-not-connect-pins-renderstream-only-on-my-logitech-came/76592885?r=SearchResults#76592885 (not an answer)
224. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76461561/how-do-i-download-whl-files-more-efficiently/76592884?r=SearchResults#76592884
225. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76337229/loading-a-large-csv-file-into-oracle-table-using-peoplecode/76592883?r=SearchResults#76592883
226. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76135179/firebase-auth-responds-with-getrecaptchaconfig-is-not-a-function-during-signin/76592882?r=SearchResults#76592882
227. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67020476/cannot-connect-to-to-fastapi-with-websocket-in-flutter-403-forbidden-code-100/76592881?r=SearchResults#76592881
228. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75865840/clarity-smart-contract-function-loop-if-error/76592880?r=SearchResults#76592880
229. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592397/how-to-regexp-replace-the-first-occurrence-of-decimal-if-theres-more-than-one-i/76592879?r=SearchResults#76592879
230. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31461902/is-it-possible-to-extend-a-default-method-implementation-of-a-trait-in-a-struct/76592877?r=SearchResults#76592877
231. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592055/adding-source-urls-in-html-requests/76592876?r=SearchResults#76592876
232. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76300671/android-getting-error-namespace-not-specified/76592875?r=SearchResults#76592875
233. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76161464/apple-pay-with-stripe-on-web-error-while-domain-verification-from-stripe-apple/76592874?r=SearchResults#76592874
234. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73782320/onbackinvokedcallback-is-not-enabled-for-the-application-in-set-androidenableo/76592871?r=SearchResults#76592871
235. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592755/how-to-get-each-sheet-url-and-set-it-in-range-a1-automatically-using-googlesheet/76592870?r=SearchResults#76592870
236. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592800/how-can-i-troubleshoot-react-issues-easier/76592867?r=SearchResults#76592867
237. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592689/sum-and-total-per-row-for-calculated-column-in-power-bi-dax/76592866?r=SearchResults#76592866
238. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76589593/cant-match-statusbar-and-view-background-color/76592865?r=SearchResults#76592865
239. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76591358/trouble-writing-real-time-segment-events-to-amazon-personalize-using-putevents/76592862?r=SearchResults#76592862
240. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592800/how-can-i-troubleshoot-react-issues-easier/76592855?r=SearchResults#76592855
241. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592803/aws-route-53-wont-validate-my-dns-certificate/76592854?r=SearchResults#76592854
242. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592503/conda-update-fails-due-to-python-version-in-base-environment/76592852?r=SearchResults#76592852
243. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592830/how-to-remove-a-limited-number-of-characters-before-a-in-a-string/76592851?r=SearchResults#76592851
244. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592816/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-close/76592846?r=SearchResults#76592846
245. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592830/how-to-remove-a-limited-number-of-characters-before-a-in-a-string/76592845?r=SearchResults#76592845
246. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76591822/microsoft-connected-cache-cannot-connect-to-and-perform-tls-handshake-with-iothu/76592840?r=SearchResults#76592840
247. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76589922/typegraphql-add-fieldresolver-for-an-array-of-object/76592836?r=SearchResults#76592836
248. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071067/php-how-to-catch-a-division-by-zero/76592833?r=SearchResults#76592833
249. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76551297/i-already-installed-32-bit-python-3-9-in-win-10-i-downloaded-it-from-the-python/76592832?r=SearchResults#76592832
250. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592732/group-by-week-date-when-start-of-week-is-monday/76592831?r=SearchResults#76592831

Comment: The "2 x deleted before I could read it" look very much like AI answers, using distinctive structuring formulations. Judging by the comments, they also failed to answer the question.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Thanks!  Doing this would be much valuable if it weren't for the problem of deleted answers.

Comment: Now I'm thinking I should have just started `https://stackoverflow.com/a/76593376` and decreased the number one by one...

Comment: #5 is almost certainly ChatGPT-generated. Some signals are phrases like *"The error you're encountering"*, the verboseness, and the absence of missing [articles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Dax90QyXgI&t=17m54s) (which is close to 100% for that area; yes, it is controversial, but it is the reality).

Comment: Just because something looks like ChatGPT doesnt mean it is.. overzealous anti-AI sentiment is running rampant

Comment: @prusswan Indeed, as you may have noticed people are already taking care here to avoid claiming posts *are* AI generated when they just have suspicions.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi see the comments to the individual questions, they only serve to drive users away if they are wrongly accused

Comment: @prusswan Indeed, the barrage of direct or thinly veiled accusations against curators is also driving away lots of people.

Comment: Given the strongly held opinions I've seen at meta.SE, I'm rather surprised to see such nuance here.

Comment: #5 received a 2nd ['Chat-GPT' Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76593966/3799241)... + Another ['ChatGPT' Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76594068/3799241) by the same User, 1h later... (The [1st Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76593366/3799241) (to #5) is also *definitely* 'ChatGPT'-generated...)

Comment: @prusswan: Show me an answer that was flagged as chatGPT generated, but actually wasn't. This suggestion that answers are getting identified as chatGPT but really aren't seems bogus. Also, the objection to AI-generated answers does not come from an anti-AI brigade but rather from the folks who make a real effort to curate the site.

Comment: @prusswan ChatGPT is destroying the value in SO. Prosus paid good money for SO

Comment: Judging from this "snapshot", Stack Overflow is still far more signal than noise.

Comment: #165 is clearly human, much too concise for AI.

Comment: #219 is human, answerer has high rep. Answer contains 99% code.

Comment: #47 and #49 are duplicates

Comment: You can also look at a users profile when determining whether a post is AI written. I recently saw a user whose entire account was AI generated.

Comment: #165 answered by Microsoft MVP  ...  https://mvp.microsoft.com/en-us/PublicProfile/5001096?fullName=Karen%20S%20Payne

Comment: I looked at 10 answers from the middle of the list and did not recognize any AI generated answer. They were rather problematic in that they sometimes presented only code or only a single line without much context or a link only. The usual stuff. There were only two answers out of ten which looked like they contain enough context (from high rep users).

Comment: @user10186832 - eating popcorn  Thanks!  It seems the links are to different answers to the same question, and one has been deleted.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones "Judging from this "snapshot", Stack Overflow is still far more signal than noise." I agree--the LLM answers here are a small percentage, and I think the overall quality is reasonably good (still). But if you imagine Stack Overflow as curating a Wikipedia-style, high-quality, verified programming resource, it'd be a potentially serious problem if 1 out of every 25 Wikipedia articles you visited was AI generated (and probably inaccurate, based on what we see here), no? I guess we can each decide what threshold is tolerable. For me, it's 0% since I can just ask the LLM directly.

Comment: @prusswan: You are confused, the people that you are suggesting should leave actually built this site and gave it value. They should stay and keep fighting the good fight. Also, I noticed you neglected to find a single incorrectly evaluated chatGPT answer, meaning you don't know of any.

Comment: "*Judging from this "snapshot", Stack Overflow is still far more signal than noise.*" there are AI-generated answers, but there are also just plainly low-quality answers. Those may overlap, but the long-standing quality problem is not only about AI...

Comment: @AndrewT. There is AI noise and human noise. And there is human signal. The question is currently if there is also AI signal. Opinions on that differ.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones When you have a moment, can you update the "3 x suspected AI" segment? We have at least 7 deleted and virtually uncontestable GPT answers at this point, with 4 more suspected. Thanks.

Comment: Some objectives on methodology: 1. The sample size is too small to represent Stack Overflow as a whole, 2. The 4-hour interval introduces a geographical bias. 3. The judgement isn't objective (i.e. based on our own limited experience) so the result can't be objective. Although it must have taken a considerable amount of time to write this question, I can't but doubt how useful this operation is. We won't ever judge all posts, let alone come to an agreed verdict on them. So what's left is a public opinionated discussion on a couple of arbitrary cases. I don't think we gain anything from that.

Comment: Another consideration: "we would expect the number to be particularly high, since this sample was taken during a moderator strike" but how quickly do mods operate normally? It takes time for flags to be acted upon even when they're not striking, likely more than 4 hours, so it's probably a non-factor here.

Comment: @ggorlen--onLLMstrike It's tricky; I can't see them.  But they're in your answer, right?  That covers it.  I can add a link to that.

Comment: I wonder if sampling 250 answers on a Saturday may give different results than a weekday like Monday to Friday (these are the common workdays in Europe, but it can vary by country, region, etc.).

Comment: Note that even with the strike, problematic content still gets deleted. So checking for problematic content without the ability to include/view deleted posts is... problematic. A shorter sample window but sampled more often may give more accurate results.

Answer (score 20):

Here's a potential GPT user who is responsible for two of the posts in this batch: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7066658/ali

- [The problem of misdiagnosing the max() function in returning the largest feature value of nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592360/the-problem-of-misdiagnosing-the-max-function-in-returning-the-largest-feature/76592917#76592917) (looks like GPT)
- [Pandas is not aggregating correctly a simple data frame. Is it a bug, or my platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592932/pandas-is-not-aggregating-correctly-a-simple-data-frame-is-it-a-bug-or-my-plat/76592958#76592958) (hard to say, but likely GPT given the context)

But most of their other [recent answers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Img3.png) look GPT-made.

---

Other virtually certain LLM answers from the batch, all [deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools):

- [Jpa @Query Annotation problem with using IN clause with java ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76593358/jpa-query-annotation-problem-to-use-in-clause-with-java-arraylist/76593366#76593366) ([another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76593966/6243352) in the same thread is also LLM-likely)
- [Android biometric - How to detect biometric is lockout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76593125/android-biometric-how-to-detect-biometric-is-lockout/76593142#76593142)
- [Google Sign-In Not Working in Next.js with Firebase due to Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76555769/google-sign-in-not-working-in-next-js-with-firebase-due-to-cross-origin-opener-p/76593135#76593135)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76593107/langchain-how-to-get-the-pdf-page-number-when-showing-a-result/76593134#76593134
- [Running two Streamlit functions at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592916/running-two-streamlit-functions-at-the-same-time/76593029#76593029) (same [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22157685/prateek) as the answer above)
- [TypeORMError: Driver not Connected - NestJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592082/typeormerror-driver-not-connected-nestjs/76593006#76593006)

Suspicious-looking answers that I'm less certain are AI generated, but may well be:

- [Why does it say module has no attribute text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76593096/why-does-it-say-module-has-no-attribute-text/76593189#76593189) (very likely ChatGPT in light of [this newer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76597140/6243352) from the same [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19858756/ben) which is almost certainly ChatGPT)
- [How can I troubleshoot React issues easier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592800/how-can-i-troubleshoot-react-issues-easier/76592867#76592867)
- [Conda update fails due to Python version in "base" environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592503/conda-update-fails-due-to-python-version-in-base-environment/76592852#76592852)

---

I didn't count the number of non-LLM spam posts, or the number of low-quality posts in general, or the ratio of correct-to-incorrect answers (this is hard to say) but I would estimate that LLM answers roughly equal the number of spam posts from this batch, about 10 out of 250. Of those LLM answers, maybe two or three are correct (I can improve the guesstimate after SME weigh-in).

I doubt this exercise will impact the debate much either way--both sides can probably see what they want in it. It's hard to draw conclusions from such a small sample, especially since deleted posts weren't considered and random factors like time of day and weekend vs weekday (among other things) weren't accounted for. I took a different angle in [this SE meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387575/examples-of-chatgpt-being-right-and-wrong-on-stack-exchange/390376#390376) which breaks down all of the LLM flags I've raised. The experience I share there matches this in that the obvious LLM answers are low-quality.

While the numbers of LLM posts here may appear low, I don't see any reason not to delete these LLM answers, as most seem useless. The moderation activity that's occurred on the LLM answers in this batch seems to be a clear improvement for the site, just as much as the non-controversial moderation activity that's occurred on the non-LLM spam answers in the batch.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76590374/how-to-set-boundary-condition-while-using-model-predict-in-scikitlearn-for-rando/76592304#76592304 <-- This one looks like a generated answer as well. It has that ChatGPT feel, but I can't pin-point exactly how.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I don't see that one in the batch posted by OP, so I'm not including it, although it is from the likely-LLM spammer I've identified and does look like ChatGPT (you can see it in the screenshot).

Comment: That one is from the user you've identified.

Comment: I'd argue [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592258/terraform-creating-s3-bucket/76593323#76593323) [the second "suspicious-looking answer"] is definitely not AI (it has a punctuation error ("Its"), a capitalization error ("In"), and a typo ("doing do"), and a link).

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones Agreed and removed, thanks. On closer inspection, I'm also removing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592903/radio-button-not-taking-the-value-as-expected/76592989#76592989) because the code mixes `var` and `const` and uses `"null"`, which I don't think a GPT would do.

Comment: @ggorlen--onLLMstrike The use of `"null"` is because the original question uses it.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Good call, but the answer also has grammatical problems that an LLM would not emit (has run-on sentences and missing articles like _the_), so it's definitely not LLM on further inspection. (I had limited time going through the 250, so I only looked at each post for a few seconds).

Comment: _"I doubt this exercise will impact the debate much either way"_ - especially this. This is a snapshot of Saturday morning 00:00-05:00 GMT. What do 10 GPT posts prove? 20? 50?

Comment: @CodeCaster it proves the claim that there's less than 10 a day absurd.

Comment: The 2nd bullet / "looks ok" is a code-only answer, it has verbose redundant GPTish prose describing but not clarifying the code.

Comment: @philipxy It's probably GPT, given that pretty much all of the other recent answers posted by that user are almost certainly GPT, but I'm just erring on the side of caution. It could be a GPT answer that is mostly code--I see those from time to time, or maybe the answerer removed some of the text to make it less obvious. There's just not much there to work from. I'll try to clarify my comment.

Comment: @KevinB [You don't need to analyze 250 posts for that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389928/gpt-on-the-platform-data-actions-and-outcomes/390067#390067).

Comment: I am not sure about this one being gen-AI: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76592862/6461462 the language is a bit different from what I've seen from the chatbots.

Comment: @M--ßţřịƙïñĝ I'm not sure, either, which is why it's in the "maybe" category. The language and code are fairly rigid, with precise capitalization and syntax, and I've seen ChatGPT do the `...` ellipses before. It's also the user's only answer, which gives less context but tends to correlate to GPT. Nonetheless, there's not much text to work from, and you're right, it's missing some of the typical ChatGPT smells like "The error message you're encountering suggests that..." etc. If the user goes on to post clearly GPT answers, then this one may be worth another look, otherwise it's probably OK.

Comment: @M--ßţřịƙïñĝ Another thing that makes me think that answer may be ChatGPT is the rhythm of "<longer explanation> <code> <short concluding sentence that explains the code>". Also, "This error is a consequence..." is not that far off from "The error message you're encountering...". But both of these patterns are fairly common, so it could be happenstance.

Comment: eh, i'd put that one in column not gpt. if there's no history of other gpt posts, and the only thing we have to go on is perfect english and it's a well written/correct answer, no blatant GPTisms, there's no reason to throw that answer into the "maybe should be actioned" group.

Comment: @ggorlen--onLLMstrike I am definitely not an SME there. I failed to read the "suspicious-looking" part and just clicked on the links, one after another. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: All right, I'll remove it then. Thanks for the feedback. I'm calling it "roughly 1 out of 25 were GPT in this batch", if that seems like a fair analysis.

Comment: @CodeCaster there's nothing wrong with further disproving it, given it's still the current method being used as the "gold standard" even today. ;)

Comment: @KevinB I mean that one random sample collected over four hours on a weekend day does little to demonstrate the problem or prove lack thereof.

Comment: @CodeCaster i mean, it does, if in one 4 hour period on a slow day we can find 10-20 examples, it's blatantly obvious the metric saying we get 10 a day is wrong.

Comment: @KevinB I am not contesting that the metric is wrong, refer to my earlier posted answer. My statistcs are rusty, but I think that from such a small, non-representative sample you cannot extrapolate meaningful conclusions. That's all I'm saying. It doesn't seem like this question asks for discussion. It's unclear to me why this question was posted.

Comment: @CodeCaster "It's unclear to me why this question was posted", likewise, especially since OP isn't even a Stack Overflow user, as far as I can tell, and can't see the deleted answers we've been discussing. OP has a history of pro-LLM posts on meta SE, so I suspect it's part of the agenda to discredit the strike by showing how rare LLM answers are, or how _good_ they are when they are posted. I'm unconvinced by the demonstration. If anything, this only solidifies my perception that LLM answers are being spammed without regard for accuracy and are posing a serious qualitative threat to SO.

Comment: @ggorlen I'd caution you in making statements like that– asserting an "agenda to discredit the strike" gets pretty darn close to witch-hunt territory IMO, and I don't think it's very helpful or productive. We don't need to try and separate folks into camps "for" and "against" the strike unless they themselves draw that line in the sand; labeling folks doesn't help the strike. You've also picked someone who is [very much public about how nuanced they feel about the strike](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390831), so I don't think it makes much sense trying to divine what their agenda is.

Comment: @ggorlen You also [commented under their stance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1305900) on that very post, so.... I doubly don't know where the agenda comment is coming from. I don't think the strike is benefitted by folks disparaging the nuance of others' stances on the matter.

Comment: @zcoop98 I don't think I'm disparaging their stance or conducting a witch hunt as much as trying to shed light on the possible motivation for this rather odd experiment. I don't see a problem with "suspecting" an agenda because OP came here with no apparent experience with Stack Overflow in order to run an experiment with questionable methodology, and seems to be downplaying the impact in the comments. Who wouldn't be a bit suspicious? The voting on this question (+41 as of now) seems terribly misguided. This is not the study we need.

Comment: @zcoop98 A post that'd make more sense than this would be transparent about goals and ask for feedback to determine a reasonable methodology, instead of a non-SO user just dumping a list of 250 recent questions and asking how many are "problematic". I should not have taken the bait on this one--it should have been downvoted and closed IMO until we can do the experiment/study correctly, in a transparent and unbiased manner by people who are part of the SO community and have real-world experience with identifying GPT answers.

Comment: @zcoop98 We have [an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390252/399876) from OP that claims their support for LLMs, which is a (somewhat) different thing than the strike, although the two are pretty strongly correlated. I should probably have written "discredit anti-LLM sentiment" rather than "discredit the strike". I also suspect LLM experiences differ greatly between people who are in non-SO SE sites and SO itself, which is where the likely vast majority of LLM spam is landing.

Comment: Are you allowed to post the deleted answers? How much rep do you need to see deleted answers?

Comment: @qwr you need [10k rep to view deleted answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). If I have time later, I'll screenshot the answers if nobody beats me to it (...but this is a bit beside the point here--I'm afraid I'm feeding a fundamentally flawed experiment with more evidence that will be misused/misconstrued).